# Is it possible to use alpacajs with Angular 2 or Angular 4?

Tags: angular, alpacajs

Is it possible to use alpacajs along with Angular 2 or 4? Can anybody provide any inputs on it? As i have tried searching but i didn't get any feasible answer for that. Please suggest!!!

Comment: What is the reason of its usage other than jQuery itself.

Answer (score 0):

its good feature , but since you are already using **Angular 2**, i would recommend you creating the forms and build it accross using models .
[Read This](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

Alpaca might be creating the forms according to the schema which is really cool , but prefer using the angular 2 way of doing things

Alpaca wasn't created with the intention of using it along with any framework.

Comment: Hey manish, thanks for the update, you mean its completely not possible to use both in same application. You mean its also not possible to work with Angular 1 also?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form) might help. But for now there isnt anything as such.